# How to standardize observations in a variable using Stata

Tags: stata

Using Stata/SE 13.1, I am trying to standardize my variable: ID- changing all ID numbers in the data set from "ES0001_2" to "ES0001." Not all records have ID numbers with "_2". Is there a command I can use to accomplish this? Many thanks.

Comment: help replace for basic help here. replace id = "ES0001" if id == "ES0001_2" is, on this information, what you seek.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/618626-standardizing-values-for-variable-removing-end-part-of-string Standard forum etiquette is to tell a forum about cross-posting.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was looking for a command that can edit over 1000 records of differing ID numbers- some with "_2" at the end, some with not. I also did post this on www.statalist.org, and did not receive a response, which is why I am seeking help from other forums.

Comment: Precisely when you post questions is immaterial in my view. You waited no more than a few minutes before cross-posting: replies do not usually come that fast. It's simple courtesy to be explicit about cross-posting.

Comment: Apologies. As a novice to the forum world, I will keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide code and your failed attempts for future questions. Just asking for code to do this or that is considered off-topic by some of us at this site. It also shows you've done your part of the job; mainly research your question before asking for help.

Depending of the structure of the values in your data set, this might or might not work (your example data might be too simple):

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
str15 id
ES0001_2
ES0003
ES0004_2
ES0008_2
end

list

*----- what you want -----

gen id2 = subinstr(id, "_2", "", .)

list
```

See `help string functions`.